# Ionic 3 project cannot be built for ios after installing OneSignal plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, onesignal, ionic3

I created a new project and installed OneSignal plugin.

> sudo ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
>
> sudo npm install --save @ionic-native/onesignal

---

After that I built for Android was okay, yet I built for iOS.

> sudo ionic cordova build ios

---

It gave me a message like this -->

```
    Lolzzs-MacBook-Pro:myOnesignal lolzzlolzz$ sudo ionic cordova build ios
> cordova platform add --save ios
✖ Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova platform add --save ios (exit code 1):

        Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.4.0
        Adding ios project...
        Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
                Path: platforms/ios
                Package: io.ionic.starter
                Name: MyApp
        iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.4.0
        Installing "cordova-plugin-console" for ios
        Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for ios
        Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for ios
        Installing "cordova-plugin-statusbar" for ios
        Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
        Installing "ionic-plugin-keyboard" for ios
        Installing "onesignal-cordova-plugin" for ios
        Failed to install 'onesignal-cordova-plugin': undefined
        Error: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in
 `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)

        Usage:

            $ pod COMMAND

              CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.

        Commands:
+ cache      Manipulate the CocoaPods cache
            + env        Display pod environment
            + init       Generate a Podfile for the current directory
            + install    Install project dependencies according to versions from a
                         Podfile.lock
            + ipc        Inter-process communication
            + lib        Develop pods
            + list       List pods
            + outdated   Show outdated project dependencies
            + repo       Manage spec-repositories
            + setup      Setup the CocoaPods environment
            + spec       Manage pod specs
            + update     Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock

        Options:

            --silent     Show nothing
            --version    Show the version of the tool
            --verbose    Show more debugging information
            --no-ansi    Show output without ANSI codes
            --help       Show help banner of specified command
                from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/comma
nd.rb:47:in `run'
                from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top
 (required)>'
                from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
                from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Why are you building with sudo?  I think the error is pretty clear in this case:  You cannot run CocoaPods as root

Comment: You shouldn't be using sudo to install plugins either

Comment: @tier1 I am using Mac and I put sudo to avoid permissions denied but I will try again without sudo and thank you I will test again :-D

Comment: @KampongChamUser Facing the same issue. Let me know how did you fix it

Answer (score 3):

after a long time trying to build my project with the exact same error with oneSignal

I saw a instruction to go to platform/ios 
and run:

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

and

`pod install --repo-update`

and that worked

Answer (score 1):

delete your node_module, platform and plugin

remove package-lock.json,

**`npm install --- don't use sudo`**

then execute the add platform with allow from root flag in buildflag

**`ionic cordova platform add ios --buildflag="--allow-root"`**

and then

**`ionic cordova build ios`**